# Is it possible to use a facebook application on more than one domain?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, dns

Is it possible to use a facebook application on more than one domain (*not* sub domains but a completely different domain)?

Let me show sample I get error. http://www.hazirportal.com/testler/test1.html this page has an login page when you click the login button it works well. http://www.hazirport.com/testler/test1.html this page has same login section and when you click it give 191 error. So could I change redirect uri to success this authorization. Or how to make my application to use it more than one domain?

Comment: No, you can't use different domains on the same facebook application

Comment: Thanks Nitzan. I realize that if I change mobile url to com.com I can insert new domains to the list of my application's app domains.

Comment: That sounds like a bug. Faecbook don't want you to have that possibility. I would not rely on this trick.

Comment: Yes. That can be a bug. But we have a lot of domains and we want to use same app on all of them.I wish It could be posible.